# my data showing undefined in Angular HTML template

Tags: angular

I am following Angular Tour of Heroes and I am having this weird error, which does not exist in the tutorial despite the codes are the same as mine.

```
  //heroes.component.ts file

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero'
import { HEROES } from '../mock-hero'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
 })
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

 heroes: Hero[] = HEROES
 constructor() {
  }

 ngOnInit() {
  }
 }
 
 //mock-hero.ts file

import { Hero } from './heroes/hero';
export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
//template 
    <h2>My Heroes</h2>
    <ul class="heroes">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.name}}</span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>{{hero.name | uppercase}} <br>Details</h3>
    <div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
   <div>
   <label for="name">Hero name: </label>
   <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
   </div>
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
 import { HEROES } from './mock-hero'


 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   HeroesComponent

   ],
   imports: [
   BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
   ],
   providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problem now is that mt heroes data, in hero.name and hero.id are undefined in my console. Please what is the problem here, because I can't seem to find any

Answer (score 1):

The html template is referring a property `hero` from component which is not available. Try to enclose below section of html template with structural directive `*ngFor`

```html
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <h3>{{hero.name | uppercase}} <br>Details</h3>
    <div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
        <label for="name{{hero.id}}">Hero name: </label>
        <input id="name{{hero.id}}" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
</div>
```

`*ngFor` in above repeats enclosed html in client with each `hero` item from property `heroes`